# file upload not working - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have tried to upload the image but it's not working, before adding the upload section code it 
    was working properly and all the entries from the form are 
    properly stored in database 
    but now the form 
    text field are also not working..

**CONTROLLER-**
  i have tried below code.but its not working.please anyone help me to solve this?

```
public function index(){
                            // if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
                            //  redirect('register/login');
                            // }
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'required');
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'DOB', 'required');
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('height', 'Height', 'required');
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('weight', 'Weight', 'required');
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('optselect', 'Complexion', 'required');
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email already exists.', 'required');

                            if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

                                $this->load->view('templates/pheader');
                                $this->load->view('profile/aboutme');
                                $this->load->view('templates/pfooter');
                            } else {
                                //Upload Image
                                $path = './assets/uploads/profilepic';
                                $config['upload_path'] = $path;
                                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                                $config['max_size'] = 15000;
                                $config['max_width'] = 1920;
                                $config['max_height'] = 1080;

                                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                                if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                                    echo "lol";
                                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                                    $this->session->set_flashdata('file_error', $this->upload->display_errors());
                                    $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
                                    exit();
                                }else{
                                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                                    $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                                }

                                $this->profile_model->about($post_image);
                                redirect('profile/vabout');
                            }
                        }
```

**VIEW-**

```
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 text-right">Upload Profile Pic:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

**MODEL-**

```
public function about($post_image){
                        $data = array(
                                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                                'location'=>$this->input->post('location'),                 
                                'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
                                'optradio' => $this->input->post('optradio'),
                                'height'=>$this->input->post('height'),
                                'weight'=>$this->input->post('weight'),
                                'optselect'=>$this->input->post('optselect'),
                                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                                'web'=>$this->input->post('web'),
                                'awards'=>$this->input->post('awards'),
                                'cw'=>$this->input->post('cw'),
                                'pp'=>$this->input->post('pp'),
                                'youtube'=>$this->input->post('youtube'),
                                'fb'=>$this->input->post('fb'),
                                'ld'=>$this->input->post('ld'),
                                'tw'=>$this->input->post('tw'),
                                'insta'=>$this->input->post('insta'),
                                'image'=> $post_image
                            );

                        return $this->db->insert('profile', $data);
                    }
```

Comment: You don't have the file field name `$this->upload->do_upload('somefieldname')`

Comment: I tried that but did not work

Comment: if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))

Comment: @SohailShaikh which os ubuntu ? or windows?

Comment: Windows @VijaySharma

Comment: @SohailShaikh replace `$this->upload->do_upload()` to `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')`

Comment: @SohailShaikh also at the end of this `$path = './assets/uploads/profilepic/'; place `/` forward slash.

Comment: Nope, it did not work either @VijaySharma

Comment: @SohailShaikh may no the error what you getting

Comment: @VijaySharma   Error: You did not select a file to upload.

Comment: What is your form tag like

Comment: Don't know why it happened. Please help meeee

Comment: <form method="post" id="aboutme" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile/index" name="aboutme" >   @wolfgang1983

Comment: @SohailShaikh did you use `enctype="multipart/form-data" ` in form tag

Comment: I would recommed using codeigniter form helper, And use form_open_multipart(); explaind here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart dont for get to load the helper in controller or autoload it.

Comment: @SohailShaikh try to added `enctype` then check it will work

Comment: thanks! It worked... @VijaySharma, . I am noob

Comment: thanks! It worked...  @wolfgang1983

Comment: okay.... Thanks @

Comment: @SohailShaikh please upvote n close your question

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
```